# VueJS - Axios Interceptors not recieving 401 response

Tags: javascript, axios, httprequest

I am trying to have a request and response interceptor setup for Axios when I make Post requests, however I can only get the request interceptor to respond, and nothing else, I've included an example of it not running:

Here is the axios setup:

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://btk7dl15c9.api.quickmocker.com";

axios.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    console.log("request ok");
    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("request error");
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    console.log("response ok");
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("response error");
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export default {
  methods: {
    axiosPost(url, data) {
      return axios.post(url, data);
    }
  }
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-shockley-xccsx

I need to be able to intercept 401 to be able to make a token refresh call (not included with the example)

Comment: nothing wrong in your code. 
even your example is working. look at the console log 
`Error: Request failed with status code 401`

Comment: The issue is that I want to be able to capture that error, with the interceptors, as I will need to be able to refresh tokens

Comment: yes the interceptor is not working. even if the response is 401

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `"axios": "0.21.2"` which it seems to have a bug in the interceptor that they fixed in `v0.21.3`

if you up to `0.21.3` or down to `0.21.1` this should fix your issue.

checkout the release log : https://github.com/axios/axios/releases/tag/0.21.3

Comment: This fixes it! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For others trying to troubleshoot this problem, if the accepted answer did not work for you, check for something like this in your code:

```
axios.defaults.validateStatus = () => {
  return true
}
```

I added this to my `main.js` so response codes >= 300 do not throw errors. This means all responses go to the first function in my interceptor. When I moved my 401 handling to the interceptor's first function, the interceptor worked as expected.